# Python. Почему одинаковые элементы в списке имеют одинаковый индекс?

Tags: python, list, index

```
def multiple_of_index(arr):
    return [arr.index(i) for i in arr]
print (multiple_of_index([68, -1, 1, -7, 10, 10]))
```

Фактический результат:  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, **4**]
Ожидаемый результат: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, **5**]

1. Почему одинаковые элементы в этом случае имеют одинаковый индекс?
2. Как действовать чтобы получить правильные индексы?

Comment: Потому что они одинаковые. Как функции index отличить один 10 от другого 10, если они одинаковые?

Comment: Если, судя по названию функции, вы хотите умножить число на индекс, то `return [i*x for i, x in enumerate(arr)]` и функция index тут вообще не нужна

Comment: *Почему одинаковые элементы в списке имеют одинаковый индекс?* - они имеют разные индексы, просто функция `index()` возвращает индекс первого совпадения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исходя из документации `index()`:

> Return the smallest i such that i is the index of the first occurrence of x in the array.

А значит одинаковый индекс у них потому что так делает функция `index(elem)` - возвращает минимальную позицию, на которой надохидтся elem.

Получить правильные индексы можно, например, так:

```
[i for i in range(len(your_list))]
```

Answer (score 3):

как только что отметил @andreymal, у вас в `arr` лежат две десятки. когда вы запрашиваете индекс десятки, функция `index()` возвращает индекс первой встреченной десятки.

чтобы получить правильные индексы, в вашем случае, достаточно просто вывести список длинны массива:

```
return list(range(len(arr)))
```